# Python/Kivy : pass TextInput text from one class to another class

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

When i run `test.py` then shows a `name` TextInput.When i type into TextInput then shows a `Tree View` with `filter` TextInput.When i Type something into `filter` TextInput it shows result according type `keyword`.
But I want when someone type in `name` TextInput then type `keyword` put into `filter` TextInput and result should be show according pass `keyword`.

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewLabel, TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
Window.size = (500, 400)


def populate_tree_view(tree_view, parent, node):
    if parent is None:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True))
    else:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True), parent)

    for child_node in node['children']:
        populate_tree_view(tree_view, tree_node, child_node)



class TreeViewLabel(Label, TreeViewNode):
    pass


class TreeviewGroup(Popup):
    treeview = ObjectProperty(None)
    tv = ObjectProperty(None)
    popup = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self,obj, **kwargs):
        super(TreeviewGroup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text=""),
                       hide_root=False,
                       indent_level=4)

        rows = [('test{}').format(i) for i in range(1, 20)]

        tree = [{'node_id': r, 'children': []} for r in rows]

        self.tv.bind(minimum_height=self.treeview.setter('height'))
        for branch in tree:
            populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, branch)
        self.treeview.add_widget(self.tv)

    def filter(self, f):
        #self.ti.text = "text12"
        self.treeview.clear_widgets()
        self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text=""),
                           hide_root=False,
                           indent_level=4)

        rows = [('test{}').format(i) for i in range(1, 20)]

        tree = []

        for r in rows:
            tree.append({'node_id': r, 'children': []})
        new_tree = []
        for n in tree:
            if f.lower() in n['node_id'].lower():
                new_tree.append(n)
        for branch in new_tree:
            populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, branch)

        self.treeview.add_widget(self.tv)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        for child in [child for child in self.treeview.children]:
            self.treeview.remove_widget(child)


class GroupScreen(Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    popup = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_groups(self, instance):
        if len(instance.text) > 0:
            if self.popup is None:
                self.popup = TreeviewGroup(self)
            self.popup.open()


class Group(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Group().run()
```

## test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<TreeViewLabel>:
    on_touch_down:
        app.root.name.text = self.text
        app.root.popup.dismiss()

<TreeviewGroup>:
    treeview: treeview
    title: "Select"
    title_size: 17
    size: 800, 800
    auto_dismiss: False
    scroll: scroll
    fltr : fltr

    BoxLayout
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id : fltr
            size_hint_y: .13
            on_text: root.filter(self.text)

        ScrollView:
            id: scroll
            size_hint: 1, .9


            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                id: treeview

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            size_hint: .5, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': 1}
            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release: root.dismiss()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()

<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.150

GroupScreen:
    name: name

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 10, 10
        row_default_height: '40dp'

        CustomLabel:
            text: ' '

        CustomLabel:
            text: ' '

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Name'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: name
            text:' '
            multiline: False
            on_text: root.display_groups(self)



        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass the whole word e.g. *keyword* or *0*, replace *on_text* with *on_text_validate*.

## DRY - Don't Repeat Yourselves

There are duplicate codes, I have turned them into modules for easy maintenance.

```
def create_treeview_root(self):
...
def create_treeview_branch(self, obj):
...
def dismiss_callback(self):
```

## Snippet

```
GroupScreen:
    ...
        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: name
            focus: True
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: root.display_groups(self)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewLabel, TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty, ListProperty
Window.size = (500, 400)


def populate_tree_view(tree_view, parent, node):
    if parent is None:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True))
    else:
        tree_node = tree_view.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True), parent)

    for child_node in node['children']:
        populate_tree_view(tree_view, tree_node, child_node)


class TreeViewLabel(Label, TreeViewNode):
    pass


class TreeviewGroup(Popup):
    treeview = ObjectProperty(None)
    tv = ObjectProperty(None)
    filter_text = StringProperty('')
    tree = ListProperty([])

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(TreeviewGroup, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.create_treeview_root()
        rows = [('test{}').format(i) for i in range(1, 20)]
        self.tree = [{'node_id': r, 'children': []} for r in rows]
        self.tv.bind(minimum_height=self.treeview.setter('height'))
        self.create_treeview_branch(self.tree)

    def create_treeview_root(self):
        self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text=""),
                           hide_root=False,
                           indent_level=4)

    def create_treeview_branch(self, obj):
        for branch in obj:
            populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, branch)
        self.treeview.add_widget(self.tv)

    def on_open(self):
        self.filter_text = App.get_running_app().root.name.text

    def dismiss_callback(self):
        self.treeview.clear_widgets()
        self.dismiss()
        App.get_running_app().root.name.focus = True

    def filter(self, f):
        self.treeview.clear_widgets()
        self.create_treeview_root()
        new_tree = []
        for n in self.tree:
            if f.lower() in n['node_id'].lower():
                new_tree.append(n)
        self.create_treeview_branch(new_tree)


class GroupScreen(Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    popup = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_groups(self, instance):
        if len(instance.text) > 0:
            if self.popup is None:
                self.popup = TreeviewGroup(self)
            self.popup.open()


class Group(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test.kv')
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Group().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<TreeViewLabel>:
    on_touch_down:
        app.root.name.text = self.text
        app.root.popup.dismiss_callback()

<TreeviewGroup>:
    treeview: treeview
    title: "Select"
    title_size: 17
    size: 800, 800
    auto_dismiss: False
    scroll: scroll
    fltr : fltr

    BoxLayout
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id : fltr
            focus: True
            text: root.filter_text
            size_hint_y: .13
            on_text: root.filter(self.text)

        ScrollView:
            id: scroll
            size_hint: 1, .9


            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                id: treeview

        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            size_hint: .5, 0.1
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': 1}
            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss_callback()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release:
                    root.dismiss_callback()

<CustomLabel@Label>:
    text_size: self.size
    valign: "middle"
    padding_x: 5

<SingleLineTextInput@TextInput>:
    multiline: False

<GreenButton@Button>:
    background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.parent.height * 0.150

GroupScreen:
    name: name

    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        padding : 30,30
        spacing: 10, 10
        row_default_height: '40dp'

        CustomLabel:
            text: ' '

        CustomLabel:
            text: ' '

        CustomLabel:
            text: 'Name'

        SingleLineTextInput:
            id: name
            focus: True
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: root.display_groups(self)

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Ok'

        GreenButton:
            text: 'Cancel'
            on_press: app.stop()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - Typed keyword]
[image: Img03 - keyword at Filter after pressed ENTER]
[image: Img04 - Typed 0 (zero)]
[image: Img05 - 0 (zero) at Filter after pressed ENTER]